# Query a specific name within the same table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, select

Table devices:

```
Name: Router1
Type: NODE
Class: Main

Name: Router1
Type: IF
Class: T1 0/0/1

Name: Router1
Type: IF
Class: Fa 0/1
```

The above is a minimal example.

The output I desire is:

```
Router1 | T1 0/0/1, Fa 0/1
```

Is this possible without creating temp tables, procedure, or a script?

I've thought deeply, but in the real world example there are multiple devices I need their IFs class from.  You cannot just pull each device in any way I know.

Comment: you condition is to group them by type "IF"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT on class column while group them according to name

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(class)
FROM devices
GROUP BY Name
WHERE Type= 'IF'
/*WHERE Name = 'Router_1'*/
```

Comment: No way to do this for every device in the database? I know you can do it that way, but say there are 100 devices with all different IFs? I tired a sub-query.

Comment: Now this will work for all generllay test it, i have updated the answer @KirsKringle

Comment: Man I had that but without GROUP BY and I was racking my brain what is wrong with me.  I can't believe I couldn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: you condition is to group them by type?

Comment: @KirsKringle my pleasure, i have added where clause for 'Type' also, you and upvote and accept it as an answer if it helps :)